# Add a child node to an inline SVG with JavaScript. Imposible on IE9?

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, internet-explorer-9

I just want add a new text node in a SVG on a html using accion() javaScript function:

```
<!DOCTYPE> 
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function accion(){
        var SVGDocument = document.getElementById("idSVG");
        var text2 = SVGDocument.createTextNode("text");
        SVGDocument.appendChild(text2);
}       
</script>
</head>

<input type="button" onclick="accion()" value="GO!!"/>

<svg id="idSVG">
   <text id="texto" x="50" y="35" font-size="14">PRUEBA</text>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

But `SVGDocument.createTextNode("text");` return an error: `Object does not support this property or method`. I think the problem is I can't get a correct reference to idSVG element. I'm using IE9.

Comment: Object does not support this property or method.

Comment: Apparently you're using IE9. I don't think that IE9 supports SVG like this, does it?

Comment: I'm Think so, I have spent days trying to modify my svg, in many ways (embed, in a object tag, with javascript on the svg itself...etc...) But is impossible.And on IE7 it was working fine...

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVG repaint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263902/svg-repaint)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The example below works for me.

Note that if you don't set a y co-ordinate the default 0, 0 is likely outside the svg bounding box.

```
<!DOCTYPE> 
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function accion(){
        var svg = document.getElementById("idSVG");
        var text2 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
        text2.setAttribute("y", "100");
        var textContent = document.createTextNode("this is the text content");
        text2.appendChild(textContent);
        svg.appendChild(text2);
}       
</script>
</head>

<input type="button" onclick="accion()" value="GO!!"/>

<svg id="idSVG">
   <text id="texto" x="50" y="35" font-size="14">PRUEBA</text>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```