# svg cannot show tooltip normally in IE but normal Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I cannot show the tooltip normally in IE but normally in Chrome.

1. Used some js codes to create dynamical label called *title*.
2. Add it into the svg.
3. Everything is right in Chrome with tooltip, but not in IE.

```
<svg id="lang-picker-toggler" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
      <path d="M217.982 201.586h-64.499c-5.537 0-10.026 4.489-10.026 10.026s4.489 10.026 10.026 10.026h53.547c-4.72 25.263-26.935 44.446-53.547 44.446-30.037 0-54.473-24.436-54.473-54.473s24.436-54.473 54.473-54.473c14.55 0 28.229 5.667 38.518 15.955 3.916 3.916 10.264 3.916 14.178 0 3.916-3.916 3.916-10.264 0-14.178-14.077-14.077-32.791-21.829-52.697-21.829-41.094 0-74.525 33.431-74.525 74.525 0 41.094 33.431 74.525 74.525 74.525s74.525-33.431 74.525-74.525c.001-5.536-4.488-10.025-10.025-10.025z"/>
      <path d="M470.331 92.24H269.728l-26.935-81.355a10.025 10.025 0 00-9.518-6.875H41.669C18.693 4.01 0 22.703 0 45.679v332.412c0 22.976 18.693 41.669 41.669 41.669h203.145l27.073 81.369a10.026 10.026 0 009.513 6.861h188.932c22.976 0 41.669-18.693 41.669-41.669V133.909c-.001-22.976-18.694-41.669-41.67-41.669zM41.669 399.708c-11.919 0-21.616-9.697-21.616-21.616V45.679c0-11.919 9.697-21.616 21.616-21.616h184.364l70.691 213.516a.366.366 0 00.015.043l53.664 162.086H41.669zm295.78-116.433c.805 1.11 10.824 14.877 26.355 34.066-4.377 5.756-9.015 11.474-13.91 17.036l-29.712-89.74h87.441c-6.196 13.031-16.938 33.813-31.692 55.736-13.553-16.921-22.069-28.622-22.249-28.87-3.251-4.482-9.519-5.481-14.002-2.23-4.482 3.25-5.48 9.518-2.231 14.002zM265.946 419.76h75.162l-55.503 59.084-19.659-59.084zm226.002 46.561c0 11.919-9.697 21.616-21.616 21.616H304.575l67.015-71.339-.004-.003c.293-.312.571-.64.823-.991a10.025 10.025 0 001.39-9.022l-16.688-50.402c7.073-7.406 13.68-15.143 19.805-22.965 13.299 15.772 29.037 33.446 45.778 50.187 1.957 1.957 4.524 2.937 7.089 2.937s5.132-.979 7.089-2.937c3.916-3.916 3.916-10.264 0-14.178-17.461-17.461-34.013-36.244-47.687-52.632 21.251-30.503 35.033-59.504 40.535-71.954h21.454c5.537 0 10.026-4.489 10.026-10.026s-4.489-10.026-10.026-10.026h-66.173v-18.047c0-5.537-4.489-10.026-10.026-10.026s-10.026 4.489-10.026 10.026v18.046h-51.406l-37.178-112.292H470.33c11.919 0 21.616 9.697 21.616 21.616v332.412z"/>
</svg>
```

Here is my javascript:

```js
// Create dynamically label for tooltip
var titleEle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'title');
var textString = document.createTextNode(currentLangElement.getAttribute('data-language'));
titleEle.appendChild(textString);
langPickerTogglerElement.appendChild(titleEle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE will not show any tooltip for the `<title>` element of the root `<svg>` element.

```css
svg {border: 1px solid}
```

```html
<svg>
  <title>IE won't show this as a tooltip</title>
  <rect x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50">
    <title>However this will be in a tooltip even in IE</title>
  </rect>
</svg>
```

[fiddle for IE](https://jsfiddle.net/egqhyvp5/embedded/result)

[Specs](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/struct.html#TitleElement) explicitly allow such behavior:

> For reasons of accessibility, user agents should always make the content of the ‘title’ child element to the root svg element available to users. However, this is typically done through other means than the tooltips used for nested SVG and graphics elements, e.g., by displaying in a browser tab.

If you wish the tooltip to appear in this browser you must set the <title> of an inner element.

In your case, it could have been a `<g>` that would contain both `<path>` elements, if it wasn't for an other IE oddity where **they show the tooltip only when you hover over painted areas** (strokes and fills).
So given your paths don't cover the whole svg element, it's kinda risky to hope for your users will hover at the correct place.

So this leaves us with a last solution, which is to append a `<rect>` which will act as an invisible background covering the whole viewPort and will handle the `<title>`.

```js
// We are now targetting the <rect> element
var langPickerTogglerElement = document.querySelector('#lang-picker-toggler > rect');
var currentLangElement = document.querySelector('[data-language]');

var titleEle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'title');
var textString = document.createTextNode(currentLangElement.getAttribute('data-language'));
titleEle.appendChild(textString);
langPickerTogglerElement.appendChild(titleEle);
```

```css
svg {border: 1px solid}
```

```html
<span data-language="My title text is awesome"></span>
<svg id="lang-picker-toggler" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="128" height="128">
  <!-- our tooltip handler, must be a graphic element for IE -->
    <!-- first element so it's set at the background -->
    <!-- cover the whole viewPort -->
    <!-- fill="none" for less work at rendering -->
    <!-- pointer-events=fill so the browser can catch mouse over -->
  <rect
    x="0" y="0" width="512" height="512"
    fill="none"
    pointer-events="fill"/>
  
  <path d="M217.982 201.586h-64.499c-5.537 0-10.026 4.489-10.026 10.026s4.489 10.026 10.026 10.026h53.547c-4.72 25.263-26.935 44.446-53.547 44.446-30.037 0-54.473-24.436-54.473-54.473s24.436-54.473 54.473-54.473c14.55 0 28.229 5.667 38.518 15.955 3.916 3.916 10.264 3.916 14.178 0 3.916-3.916 3.916-10.264 0-14.178-14.077-14.077-32.791-21.829-52.697-21.829-41.094 0-74.525 33.431-74.525 74.525 0 41.094 33.431 74.525 74.525 74.525s74.525-33.431 74.525-74.525c.001-5.536-4.488-10.025-10.025-10.025z"/>
  <path d="M470.331 92.24H269.728l-26.935-81.355a10.025 10.025 0 00-9.518-6.875H41.669C18.693 4.01 0 22.703 0 45.679v332.412c0 22.976 18.693 41.669 41.669 41.669h203.145l27.073 81.369a10.026 10.026 0 009.513 6.861h188.932c22.976 0 41.669-18.693 41.669-41.669V133.909c-.001-22.976-18.694-41.669-41.67-41.669zM41.669 399.708c-11.919 0-21.616-9.697-21.616-21.616V45.679c0-11.919 9.697-21.616 21.616-21.616h184.364l70.691 213.516a.366.366 0 00.015.043l53.664 162.086H41.669zm295.78-116.433c.805 1.11 10.824 14.877 26.355 34.066-4.377 5.756-9.015 11.474-13.91 17.036l-29.712-89.74h87.441c-6.196 13.031-16.938 33.813-31.692 55.736-13.553-16.921-22.069-28.622-22.249-28.87-3.251-4.482-9.519-5.481-14.002-2.23-4.482 3.25-5.48 9.518-2.231 14.002zM265.946 419.76h75.162l-55.503 59.084-19.659-59.084zm226.002 46.561c0 11.919-9.697 21.616-21.616 21.616H304.575l67.015-71.339-.004-.003c.293-.312.571-.64.823-.991a10.025 10.025 0 001.39-9.022l-16.688-50.402c7.073-7.406 13.68-15.143 19.805-22.965 13.299 15.772 29.037 33.446 45.778 50.187 1.957 1.957 4.524 2.937 7.089 2.937s5.132-.979 7.089-2.937c3.916-3.916 3.916-10.264 0-14.178-17.461-17.461-34.013-36.244-47.687-52.632 21.251-30.503 35.033-59.504 40.535-71.954h21.454c5.537 0 10.026-4.489 10.026-10.026s-4.489-10.026-10.026-10.026h-66.173v-18.047c0-5.537-4.489-10.026-10.026-10.026s-10.026 4.489-10.026 10.026v18.046h-51.406l-37.178-112.292H470.33c11.919 0 21.616 9.697 21.616 21.616v332.412z"/>

</svg>
```

[fiddle for IE](https://jsfiddle.net/egqhyvp5/1/embedded/result)

Answer (score 1):

There's a simpler way.  You can can just replace this:

```
var textString = document.createTextNode(currentLangElement.getAttribute('data-language'));
titleEle.appendChild(textString);
```

with this:

```
titleEle.textContent = currentLangElement.getAttribute('data-language');
```

which does work in IE.

Comment: Oh interesting, no IE to test, but [this old Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749983/add-a-child-node-to-an-inline-svg-with-javascript-imposible-on-ie9) seems to imply that *appendChild(TextNode)* should work in IE too... Do you confirm it doesn't? Anyway, *in OP's case*, `textContent` is indeed easier.

Comment: @Kaiido, No. appendChild(TextNode) doesn't work. You can have a try

Comment: @Paul LeBeau，Are you sure it works? However it doesn't work properly in IE11 and other versions.

Comment: @Beginner as I said, I can't try, "no IE to test". My comment is motivated by [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749983/add-a-child-node-to-an-inline-svg-with-javascript-imposible-on-ie9) which seems to imply that it was working at least in IE9. Such a regression seems quite surprising, hence my comment asking for confirmation from Paul, because since you are the original reporter, you may still face the original issue, which might not be the appendChild(TextNode) .

Comment: @Beginner and Paul, so I started my slow VM and that's what I thought, appendChld(TextNode) is not the problem here. What IE doesn't allow is to show the tooltip of the root's <title>. If it had been set manually in markup, the result would have been the same, and unfortunately, `textContent` wouldn't help here (even though it's still easier than the long TextNode road...)

Comment: Well okay then. That's strange. I tested it and it was working.  But I tried again now and it isn't. So I'm not sure how I stuffed up. Apologies for wasted time.