# Placing text inside svg using appendChild()

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to insert text inside SVG using `appendChild()` method. I need to use this method for the actual code I am writing.

In the attached code, you will find that I am trying to write the string "How are you?" inside the SVG using `appendChild()` method. However it doesn't display. I checked the execution using Chrome developer tools, `myTextElement` and `myText` are actually executed in the code. I don't see why it is not being displayed, though. Can you please help?

```js
var mysvg = document.getElementById("mysvg")
var myTextElement = document.createElement("text");
var myText = document.createTextNode("How are you?")

myTextElement.appendChild(myText);
mysvg.appendChild(myTextElement);
```

```css
circle {
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
  stroke-width: 4;
  fill: #3080d0;
  stroke: #3080d0;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<svg id="mysvg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="300">
  <circle id="my-circle" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" />
  <text x="0" y="10" font-family="Verdana" font-size="55" fill="blue"> Hello </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263902/svg-repaint), you need a valid namespace.

Comment: Thanks, Vadim and Adam. I was breaking my head on this past 36 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Improved positioning of `text` for demo.

```js
var mysvg = document.getElementById("mysvg");

var myTextElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
var myText = document.createTextNode("How are you?");
myTextElement.setAttribute("x", "0");
myTextElement.setAttribute("y", "110");
myTextElement.setAttribute("fill", "blue");
myTextElement.setAttribute("font-family", "Verdana");
myTextElement.setAttribute("font-size", "55");

myTextElement.appendChild(myText);
mysvg.appendChild(myTextElement);
```

```css
circle {
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
  stroke-width: 4;
  fill: #3080d0;
  stroke: #3080d0;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<svg id="mysvg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="300">
  <circle id="my-circle" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" />
  <text x="0" y="55" font-family="Verdana" font-size="55" fill="blue"> Hello </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like `<text>` elements inside `<svg>`'s need the `x` and `y` property to display the text (otherwise they will default to `0`). You can set the attributes of your text element in your `<script>`:

```
myTextElement.setAttribute('x', '20');
myTextElement.setAttribute('y', '20');
```

I'm sure these values will not be what you want, but they should allow you to see your inserted element.

One further source of error to remove - I would add your `<script>` tag just before the end of your `<body>` element, not inside your `<svg>`. I'm not certain, but with your script element where it is, the DOM element corresponding to your `<svg>` may not be defined at the time your script runs.